# How to delete used numbers in computer guessing game?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a computer vs computer guessing game and the problem is that the computer will guess the same number twice.  I tried the `.remove()` with a variable but the computer would still guess where the variable was so I would get an error.  I reverted the code back to where it worked somewhat.

```
print 'Get ready for some action!'
time.sleep(1)
firstname = raw_input('Enter in a name for computer 1... ')
time.sleep(1)
secondname = raw_input('Enter in a name for computer 2... ')
time.sleep(1)
howlittle = int(raw_input('Enter in the min... '))
time.sleep(1)
howmuch = int(raw_input('Enter in the max... '))
computernumber = random.randint(howlittle,howmuch)
print firstname + 'choses %s as its lucky number.' %computernumber
time.sleep(1)
print '%s is thinking...'%secondname
time.sleep(1)
firsts=random.randint(howlittle,howmuch)
if firsts == computernumber:
    print 'The %s won!'%secondname
guessers = 0
computers=[]
while firsts != computernumber:
    guessers += 1
    if firsts == computernumber:
        print 'The computer won in %s guesses'%guessers
    elif firsts > computernumber:
        firsts = random.randint(howlittle,firsts)
        computers.append(firsts)
    elif firsts < computernumber:
        firsts = random.randint(firsts, howmuch)
        computers.append(firsts)
print secondname + " took %s guesses to guess the number" %guessers
print computers
```

I am still adding features to it but I just needed to get this problem out of the way first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if condition in your elif such that :

if number_guessed is in computer_guesses_list:
  generate a random number again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that `random.randint(a,b)` returns a number x in [a,b], i.e. `a <= x <= b`.

So in your code, `random.randint(howlittle,firsts)` its possible for `firsts` to be returned, change it to `random.randint(howlittle,firsts-1)`

and `random.randint(firsts,howmuch)` to `random.randint(firsts+1,howmuch)`

You should have posted the code that isn't working.